problem with displaying values on a new row in Oracle Apex
I have a text item that I populate with SQL code,
I use chr(13) as the newline character, see code,
the item is populated with values, but in the view when the page is rendered, the values are in one line.
this is the code to populate the item
 for row in (select EName, Comm from EMP
                 where instr( ':'||:P18_SHARED_SALESMAN||':',  ':'||EmpNo||':' ) > 0 )
    loop
          :P18_SHARED_NEW_COMMISSIONS := :P18_SHARED_NEW_COMMISSIONS || row.EName || ': ' || row.Comm || chr(13) || chr(10); 
     end loop;

This is the result:

I expect the values to be on new lines.


I have a text item ...

That won't work; it is displayed as a single-line item.
If you want to see multiple rows, set it to be a text area item type.
